# Mac OS X runaway process: AuthBrokerAgent

Tags: macos

I'm trying to pinpoint the problem with a runaway process on my Mac (Lion 10.7.2) and I have a hard time finding any kind of info about that process on the Internet. It is simply called `AuthBrokerAgent`. I would like to know what is its function.

I'm not a developer and I didn't installed the developer tools on my Mac.

Thanks a lot!

P.S. I've already [started a thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3458072?start=0&tstart=0) on Apple Community forum.

Answer (score 3):

Problem solved. The `AuthBrokerAgent` is responsible for handling proxy credentials. If the credentials of a proxy setup are improperly stored (for example in one's keychain) then the `AuthBrokerAgent` can runaway.

More details and context on a [follow-up](https://discussions.apple.com/message/16606282#16606282) posted on Apple Community forum, but the solution was to clear out bad user/passwords from the keychain and use Safari to re-ented the correct user/pass for the web proxy and check the box to have Safari save the password in the keychain.